# Is it possible to implement Oauth 2.0 without javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

On my e commerce site I offer my users openid login.
All major providers, except facebook offered an openid endpoint this.
Facebook only offered oauth 2.0.

For that exception I set up an openid endpoint myself, where users can log in using facebooks oauth.

In other words, I created an intermediary site where the user logs in using facebook, and from there logs seamlessly into my e commerce site using openid.
This just involves header redirects and works transparent to the end user.

Now amazon [joined the league](http://login.amazon.com/) of single sign on providers. They support only oauth 2.0.

All in all oauth 2.0 seems to be the winning candidate and not openid, since all providers I care about also support oauth by now.

So I thought about implementing oauth directly into my e commerce site.

However the implementation instructions differ greatly from provider to provider.

Most require an external javascript loaded into the site. 
Loading external javascripts for every oauth provider I want to support is an option that I would like to avoid.

Facebook offers a completely server side, way, involving no javascripts.

Amazon does not.

But its all oauth 2.0 is it not?

It appears to me that either the standard is very relaxed or not consistently implemented.

Is it possible to have a generic oauth 2.0 class where I just pass the config and endpoints specific to theprovider and achieve a login?

I looked at the Zend implementation but it is really really huge...
The facebook no-javascript implementation is really small...

I am a bit lost here. Can someone point me int he right direction?

I want to implement several oauth providers. Among those for sure google, facebook, amazon and twitter.

Is it possible to make this with the same codebase, or do I have to implment them all seperately using their sdk classes and javascripts?

I could do that with no problem, but my gutts realy dont like it for several reasons (maintenance, flexibility, addint new proviers etc..)

And where is the oauth 2.0 standard in that?

Any help is appriciated.

*Personal sidenote*

> I apologize for taking this chance to briefly point out that I don't
>   like Oauth. It requires every site that uses it to register with the
>   oauth providers. Also those providers may disagree to cooperate with
>   sites. I do not like that authority, I prefer openid. I know its not
>   perfect, but I prefer it. Also openid and oauth are vulnerable by
>   design for an attack where a malicious sites lets the user click the
>   login button and opens up a spoofed provider side, where the user logs
>   in in believe that he is logging into the provider site. It cant be
>   helped, the user has to look at the url to see whether its realy the
>   desired site. I know that this is a fundamental problem and difficult
>   to handle, however I wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 4):

There's a great deal of similarity between providers and the basic flow will be the same. There's often no need for any Javascript in the browser. What each provider is giving you is just a helper to make things easier for you (if you just care about them).

It seems that you are working on a web site. For that, the OAuth 2 flow you need to implement is called the *Authorization Code Flow*. And bottom line it's just a few http(s) requests that follow a very similar pattern:

1. Redirect user to the provider
2. Login & consent pages
3. Redirect back to your site (to a registered callback address) with a `code`
4. Your website requesting an `access_token` from the provider, using the `code` from step #3 and a `client_id`/`client_secret` (essentially credentials for your web server.
5. Use the `access_token` obtained in #4 to call the provider API.

I've wrote about it [here](https://docs.auth0.com/protocols) if you want see more details. It is in the context of the [product](http://auth0.com) I'm working on, but the principles are the same.

Where things get a little bit more complicated often is:

- The permissions `scope`, which is different from one provider to another. For example: Facebook has tons of options, with very fine grained control of what you request a user to disclose (e.g friends, photos, etc). LinkedIn has fewer (e.g profile, your network, notifications). Amazon only has two (name, postal_code).

These are all very provider specific because they relate the resources they are managing. Notice that OAuth is essentially an *Authorization* protocol (often used for authentication). In many cases, if you are not going to call their API, you are fine with the minimal scope.

- User profile information. Most providers have `/userprofile` endpoint to retrieve attributes of the logged in user. But often times, each one usually implements different schemas: some use `email` other would call that `emailaddress`. Same with `last_name` vs `family_name`, etc. It is up to you to normalize the profile into something with common semantics.

For our system, we chose to map everything to the `openid connect` userinfo [standard claims](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#userinfo) where possible. Not always possible, because providers usually supply more information. ([Here's](https://docs.auth0.com/user-profile) what we actually supply)

Regarding your side note: you are right, good reasons to use SSL **always**. And also a reason some providers are adding multi-factor authentication.

Comment: now THAT was a useful answer! thanks a lot and thats a really interesting and promising porject there!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need javascript at all to implement an OAuth client. OAuth 2.0 (or 1.0) is an standard, so to connect to any site implementing OAuth you need to follow the same steps, maybe with slight variations.

In PHP I used this library, though I don't know if it fits OAuth 2.0, I worked with 1.0 and 1.0a:

- https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth
- https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth-examples

It should fit all servers you need to connect. Also, some reading about the "theory" of OAuth protocol could help you: http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: this is only oauth 1 ia m searching for a client for oauth 2 and try to make it work with all the providers...

Comment: this is taken from the speficiation: 'this specification is likely to  produce a wide range of non-interoperable implementations.' http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-30#section-1.8

Comment: Yes, there can be a range of implementations, then you should read each provider's (Facebook, Amazon...) implementation, but I guess they don't differ much. In OAuth 1.0 there was a basic autorization flow: request_token -> authorize or authenticate -> access_token, once you understand this proccess is not so difficult. Looking tmhOAuth library I linked looks like it only supports 1.0A, so maybe there is another library already implemented for 2.0 or maybe you need to implement it yourself. But, answering your first question: you can do it with pure PHP.